# Whats the difference between abstract and protected in my scenario - C#

Tags: c#, .net

What is the difference between a public abstract class with a public constructor, and a public class with a protected constructor.  We don't have any functions that are abstract in our abstract class, but we want programmers to only be capable of creating objects that extend that class.

Both scenarios compile and work, however I don't understand which would be better to use in what scenario.  I have been brought up to understand that although you cannot instantiate an abstract class directly (only through a non abstract child class), the abstract class should normally contain abstract functions that are required to be implemented by the children of that class.

Wouldn't having a protected constructor in a public class signify that instantiation of this class is not possible (this is the only constructor we have).

Comment: For what it's worth, I think an abstract class conveys the intentions of your design more clearly.

Comment: It's all well and good to understand the differences, however it more meaningful to understand "what problem do you need to solve?" Depending on your answer, the creation of an instance can be done different ways (factory class for example) which can be independent  of the declared type of class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) about using the `abstract` keyword for classes: *Use the abstract modifier in a class declaration to indicate that a class is intended only to be a base class of other classes.* That is, it is not required that an abstract class contain any abstract members. The `abstract` modifier is just an explicit way to say that the class shouldn't be instantiated, rather than with technical obstacles such as making constructors publicly invisible.

Note that the technical obstacle you described even has a caveat: It can still be called:

- It can be invoked from derived classes.
- It can be invoked by using reflection.

Both mean that other developers who are just (ab-?)using your class can do something you did not intend to happen, namely instantiate your class, and both are not possibly when making the class abstract.

**Therefore, the answer is that you should mark your classes as `abstract`.**

Note that it is adviseable to make the constructor of your abstract class protected nonetheless (to emphasize that the class cannot be instantiated). Tools such as FxCop will output a warning if an abstract class has a public constructor.

This complies with the general rule of making each member just as visible as it really needs to be. In an abstract class, constructors will never be invoked from public scope, so `public` visibility is not required. They will only ever be invoked by constructors of derived classes, so `protected` is the reasonable visiblity for any constructors in an abstract class.

**Hence, also make any constructors of your abstract classes (at most) `protected`.**

Answer (score 6):

I would do a public abstract class with a protected constructor.

Using `abstract` makes it clear that it's really an abstract class.  Just a `protected` constructor isn't as clear.

Nothing other than a sub class can call an `abstract` constructor; it's kinda meaningless to leave it `public`.

Comment: This is the way to go. There is event a [rule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182126.aspx) that enforces this.

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't understand why - doesn't the fact that the class is declared as abstract make it clear enough? I mean, reading that one word, 'abstract', tells the reader that the class IS abstract - how can it get any clearer..?

Comment: @Daniel: The idea may be to give all members their minimum required visibility. A constructor is not publicly useful in an abstract class; it will only ever be used in derived classes (in their inherited constructor call, more precisely), which is why it should be *protected*.

Comment: I mean using the abstract keyword makes it clearer.  Add "protected" to the constructor is basically sugar.  But, it does tell reviewers of the class that you understood what abstract really means :).  Nothing other than a sub class can call an abstract constructor; it's kinda meaningless to leave it public.

Comment: @PeterRitchie: You mean nothing other than a *derived* class, I presume? :-)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper yes, sub class :)

Comment: For another example: If the code gives no instance constructors at all for a class, the compiler will, as you know, write one constructor for you, the default constructor. This constructor will be `public` only if the class is non-abstract. For an abstract class this "invisible" constructor will be `protected`. See paragraph 10.11.4 of the [C# Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx). So this is one more example of the practice of not having public constructors in abstract classes.

Answer (score 4):

A private or protected constructor can still be called by static methods in the declaring class. An abstract class must have a derived class to be instantiated. For example, the singleton pattern makes use of private constructors called through a public static method/property.

Comment: I like this answer. With a non-abstract class `Base`, even if all (instance) constructors are `protected`, someone could introduce code either in `Base` itself or in some class deriving from `Base` that said: `var b = new Base(...);`

Answer (score 0):

A public abstract class with a protected or internal constructor conveys how you want calling code to use it. Using a non-accessible constructor can be actually confusing.